# Exclude file pattern from keeping it in viminfo history?

Tags: viminfo

I am comforable with using history of edited files that is kept in viminfo,
the one that sets the limit in the first setting of `set viminfo='100,...` variable.

After I've started using mutt as email client and using vim as its editor,
and that makes multiple temporary files created in /tmp/dir. These are of no interest and spoil the history of `:browse old`.
I am trying to figure out the way of excluding those so they could be skipped or at least wiped in some hook procedure. 
They all can be easily identified by `/tmp/mutt-.*` path regex.

Is there some natural/doable way to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

I guess I found a good solution for my use case. 
`-i` option allows to specify alternative locoation of viminfo file.
So I can specifey `vim -i /tmp/blackhole` for cases where I do not care of file history. In my case that is specifying

```
set editor = "vim -i /tmp/idontcare"
```

in my .muttrc

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `r` option. See `:h viminfo-r`:

```
r   Removable media.  The argument is a string (up to the next
    ',').  This parameter can be given several times.  Each
    specifies the start of a path for which no marks will be
    stored.  This is to avoid removable media.  For MS-DOS you
    could use "ra:,rb:", for Amiga "rdf0:,rdf1:,rdf2:".  You can
    also use it for temp files, e.g., for Unix: "r/tmp".  Case is
    ignored.  Maximum length of each 'r' argument is 50
    characters.
```

So in your case you can use something like

```
set viminfo='100,<1000,s100,:100,r/tmp,n$HOME/.vim/viminfo
```

Make sure the `r` option is not at the end of the list, it will break `viminfo` for some reason.